Retrieving p-value of overall significance of simple lavaan model
How can I retrieve the p-value of the overall significance of a simple lavaan model?
Just similar to the p-value for the F-statistic in standard linear regression done with lm().
model <- sem('criterion ~ predictor1 + predictor2', data = data, missing = "FIML", fixed.x = FALSE, se = "BOOTSTRAP", bootstrap = 5000)
summary(model, standardize = FALSE, ci = TRUE, rsquare = T)

EDIT: here's sample data
structure(list(predictor1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, NA, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
NA, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), predictor2 = c(23.09, 26.19, 22.77, 
19.56, 21.38, NA, 22.55, 21.06, 22.13, 24.05, 21.06, 23.94, 22.78, 
21.38, 20.74, 23.52, 23.41, 21.16, 22.34, 23.94, 22.45, 21.06, 
21.16, 20.2, 20.52, 23.19, 26.4, 22.34, 25.12, 23.09, 22.34, 
23.3, 23.19, 29.07, 23.19, 25.12, 22.66, 23.19, 22.77, 26.19, 
21.27, 23.3, 21.48, 23.73, 23.3, 21.48, 21.81, 24.16, 23.19, 
22.34, 21.59, 21.27, 25.23, 22.66, 24.05, 26.29, 23.19, 22.77, 
23.84, 23.19), criterion = c(1.97, 1.15, 0, -1.18, -0.15, 1.42, 
0, 2.19, 2.5, 1.08, 2.15, 0.27, 0.49, -0.15, 0.7, -6.93, 0.13, 
1.94, 2.09, -0.26, 0.9, 1.94, 2.26, 0.77, -1.02, 0.48, 0, 0.28, 
1.41, 1.17, 0, 0, 2.59, 4.78, 2.59, 1.16, 1.1, 1.07, -1.62, 1.1, 
0, 0, 0.35, 1.07, 0.33, -0.29, 2.12, -1.4, 0.9, 0, 5.28, -0.94, 
-1.2, 0.67, 0.72, 0, 3.13, 0, 0.62, 0.84)), row.names = c(NA, 
60L), class = "data.frame")


From here it looks as if parameterEstimates(model)$pvalue will do the job.

Sorry, I meant the overall significance of the model, just like you do on a standard linear regression by the p-value of the F-statistc.

There are a couple of options that you can try! Instead of fiddling with accessing elements of an S4 object you can pass it to summary first. The other option is letting purrr::pluck do the dirty work.
library(lavaan)
#> This is lavaan 0.6-17
#> lavaan is FREE software! Please report any bugs.
library(tidyverse)

data(PoliticalDemocracy, package = 'lavaan')

model <- '
# measurement model
ind60 =~ x1 + x2 + x3
dem60 =~ y1 + y2 + y3 + y4
dem65 =~ y5 + y6 + y7 + y8
# regressions
dem60 ~ ind60
dem65 ~ ind60 + dem60
# residual correlations
y1 ~~ y5
y2 ~~ y4 + y6
y3 ~~ y7
y4 ~~ y8
y6 ~~ y8'

fit = sem(model, data = PoliticalDemocracy, missing = "FIML")


tidyish_way = fit |> 
  pluck('test', 'standard', 'pvalue') 


base_way = summary(fit, standardize = FALSE,
 ci = TRUE, rsquare = TRUE)$test$standard$pvalue


print(tidyish_way)
#> [1] 0.3291804
print(base_way)
#> [1] 0.3291804

summary(fit)
#> lavaan 0.6.17 ended normally after 68 iterations
#> 
#>   Estimator                                         ML
#>   Optimization method                           NLMINB
#>   Number of model parameters                        31
#> 
#>   Number of observations                            75
#> 
#> Model Test User Model:
#>                                                       
#>   Test statistic                                38.125
#>   Degrees of freedom                                35
#>   P-value (Chi-square)                           0.329


Created on 2024-05-14 with reprex v2.1.0

When I run your code with my model and data, I get
Test statistic 0.000, Degrees of freedom 0, and no line for P-value (Chi-square).

Could you provide a sample of your data? It is a bit hard to see what is going on without testing it on your use case!

I added sample data in my post

In this case the associated p-value is NA so I am not sure this is a lavaan issue as an estimation issue. The set of code I provided and that @sethparker provided get the p-value with the model. The "problem" is that the p-vaslue is NA

Yes, you are right.

model <- sem('Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width', data = iris)

Instead of
summary(model, standardize = FALSE, ci = TRUE, rsquare = T)

You could try
> parameterestimates(model, standardized = F, ci = T, rsquare = T)

       lhs op          rhs    est    se      z pvalue ci.lower ci.upper
1 Sepal.Length  ~ Petal.Length  0.542 0.069  7.899  0.000    0.407    0.676
2 Sepal.Length  ~  Petal.Width -0.320 0.159 -2.012  0.044   -0.631   -0.008
3 Sepal.Length ~~ Sepal.Length  0.159 0.018  8.660  0.000    0.123    0.195
4 Petal.Length ~~ Petal.Length  3.096 0.000     NA     NA    3.096    3.096
5 Petal.Length ~~  Petal.Width  1.287 0.000     NA     NA    1.287    1.287
6  Petal.Width ~~  Petal.Width  0.577 0.000     NA     NA    0.577    0.577
7 Sepal.Length r2 Sepal.Length  0.766    NA     NA     NA       NA       NA

And isolate your desired p value (NA in this example)
> parameterestimates(model, standardized = F, ci = T, rsquare = T)$pvalue[7]

[1] NA

